# mysql query return unexpected number of rows

Tags: mysql

I have tried here to apply join on two columns.

```
SELECT 
abc.*
FROM  abc 
INNER JOIN  xyz
ON abc.column1 = xyz.column1
INNER JOIN  xyz AS xyz2
ON abc.column2 = xyz2.column2
```

The result of this query contain 81 rows with same data where as it must return the only one row.

I have tried this with DISTINCT but it does not work for me.

As result table(abc) contain there column id, column1, column2 where the data in the column1 and column2 can be repeat.

But yes the combination of column1 with column2 two never be repeat.

So how could I add the DISTINCT for two column in result.

Can anyone help me, how do i restrict to get unexpected number of row with same data??

Comment: Maybe select distinct?

Comment: You don't filter the data. WHy should it be just one row?

Comment: Please have look on revised question post.

Comment: Does xyz relate to xyz2 in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, your data is being multiplied because of multiple matches.  Perhaps you means:

```
select abc.*
from abc
where exists (select 1 from xyz where abc.column1 = xyz.column1) and
      exists (select 1 from xyz where abc.column2 = xyz.column2);
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but I can not able to select the column from xyz table.

Comment: @user3305818 . . . Your question doesn't mention selecting any columns from the `xyz` table.  It quite explicitly says `select abc.*`.